# Invoke a lambda function with deployment using serverless framework

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless

Is there a way to invoke a lambda function immediately after deployment using serverless framework. This function just creates the SNS Application, which is required to be done once only during setup.
I can use `serverless deploy stage && serverless invoke --function functionName` but that won't tear down the setup if the function fails.

I want it to be deployed as part of setup.

Thanks

Comment: I'd love to know how to do exactly this to run some migrations on deploy.  If the migration fails it should rollback to the previous deployment.

Comment: Hi @NibyNool, please refer to my answer below. Hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Hooks can be added to the lifecycle events of the Serverless framework.

I used serverless-plugin-scripts plugin(https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-plugin-scripts) to invoke custom jobs after deployment and removal of stack.

Here is an example -

```
custom:
  scripts:
    hooks:
      'deploy:finalize': sls invoke -f functionName && 
      'remove:remove': npm run scriptName && sls invoke -f anotherFunctionName
```

Now, after successful deployment via `serverless deploy`, `sls invoke -f functionName` is triggered.

Similarly, on removal using `serverless remove`, `npm run scriptName && sls invoke -f anotherFunctionName` executes.

Complete list of Serverless framework's Lifecycle events / commands is available here - https://gist.github.com/HyperBrain/50d38027a8f57778d5b0f135d80ea406

Comment: hmm but how to reference here a name of a function via variable or !Ref intrinsic function?

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this entirely fits your needs, but I've had success with configuring a Lambda function with a CloudWatch event that will trigger on CloudFormation API calls.

You'll need CloudTrail enabled to do this.

You could probably limit the function's execution to specific stacks (probably using the `resources` attribute in the [CloudTrail event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-event-reference-record-contents.html))

```
...

functions:
  stack-deployment-function:
    handler: stack-deployment-function.handler
    description: Lambda function triggered by Stack changes/deployments
    timeout: 300
    environment:
      FOO: bar
    events:
      - cloudwatchEvent:
          name: ${self:service}-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}-stack-deployment-function
          description: 'Updates XYZ after CloudFormation update'
          event:
            source:
              - "aws.cloudformation"
            detail-type:
              - "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
            detail:
              eventName:
                # Need to call DescribeStacks in Lambda to confirm successful deployment before making any changes
                - "UpdateStack"
                - "CreateStack"
```

Comment: Looks like an interesting way to do it.  Looks like it will only run when a change on cloudformation occurs, I wonder what use cases wouldn't trigger a CF update even though something has been deployed.