# AWS cron job run after deploy

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, cron-task

I have an AWS cron job which I have scheduled to run once every 3 hours.

```
 Schedule expression: rate(3 hours)
```

How do I ensure that it is run immediately after I deploy it along with it's scheduled run?

I use `serverless` framework to write my lambda and deploy to aws

```
 cron-refresh-session-token:
   handler: src/handlers/session-token/get.handler
   events:
     - schedule: rate(3 hours)
       enabled: true
```

I deploy using the command `sls deploy --stage=stageName`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525042/invoke-a-lambda-function-with-deployment-using-serverless-framework This looks like what you are asking

Comment: yes indeed it is. Thanks @JamesKn